# Java paint method not updating variable value

Tags: java, multithreading, draw

I don't understand what's going on.

This is my class

```
public class MyGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Timer timer;

private Image plyr;

public int x, y, x_pelota, y_pelota;
private boolean up, down, left, right;

public MyGame(){

    resetArrows();

    ImageIcon pertsonaiaIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("img/plyr.png"));
    pertsonaia = pertsonaiaIcon.getImage();

    timer = new Timer(15, this);
    timer.start();
}

private void resetArrows() {
    up = false;
    down = false;
    left = false;
    right = false;
}

public boolean updatePosition(String object, int x, int y) {
    if (object.equals("Player")){
        if (up) {
            this.y = y + 5;
            this.x = x;
        }else if (down) {
            this.y = y - 5;
            this.x = x;
        }else if (left) {
            this.x = x - 5;
            this.y = y;
        }else if (right) {
            this.x = x + 5;
            this.y = y;
        }else {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }else {
        //Mover pelota
    }

    resetArrows();

    //if (Math.abs(x - x_pelota) < 2 && Math.abs(y - y_pelota) < 2)
        //return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    System.out.println(this.x);
    g.drawImage(plyr, this.x, this.y, this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    switch(keyCode) { 
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        resetArrows();
        up = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        resetArrows();
        down = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        resetArrows();
        left = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
        resetArrows();
        right = true;
        break;
    }   
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
```

}

I have a Thread in another class which calls this class' updatePosition method, which should update the x and y variable values, and it does! I tried printing this.x and this.y values and the values are updated, but paint method is taking 0 and I don't understand why.

I don't know if it is because I am using threads... I don't know what to try to solve the problem.

Comment: just show the other thread - the complete program - amd you should know that JPanel has paintComponent not paint

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if it is because I am using threads...

It is! The JVM is allowed to give each thread an own *copy* of the variables. If you want to make changes from one thread visible in another thread you have to either synchronize the access or mark the variables as volatile. Synchronizing seems more appropriate as you change both variables in one go.

As a quick solution edit your methods as following:

```
public synchronized boolean updatePosition(...) { ... }
public synchronized boolean paint(...) { ... }
```

Comment: I tried both synchronizing the methods, and adding volatile to the variables, and it's still not working

Comment: fancy junk - you dont even know what happens in the other thread